# python sympy common denominator to symbolic fraction

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to generate a function that receive an expression with fractions (like `A/(p+1)+B/(p+2)`), and return the common denominator fraction and pack the common part in the numerator
(like `((A+B)p+2A+B)/((p+1)(p+2))` [the `p` taken out as a common multiples]).

There is a `together` function in `sumpy` that take the common denominator, but it does not pack the numerator.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `together` you can use `fraction` to separate the numerator and denominator and then you can process the numerator with `expand/collect`:

```
In [38]: A, B, p = symbols('A, B, p')

In [39]: A/(p+1)+B/(p+2)
Out[39]: 
  A       B  
───── + ─────
p + 1   p + 2

In [40]: e = A/(p+1)+B/(p+2)

In [41]: together(e)
Out[41]: 
A⋅(p + 2) + B⋅(p + 1)
─────────────────────
   (p + 1)⋅(p + 2)   

In [42]: fraction(together(e))
Out[42]: (A⋅(p + 2) + B⋅(p + 1), (p + 1)⋅(p + 2))

In [43]: n, d = fraction(together(e))

In [44]: n = collect(expand(n), p)

In [45]: n/d
Out[45]: 
2⋅A + B + p⋅(A + B)
───────────────────
  (p + 1)⋅(p + 2)
```

Comment: Actually a simpler way to get to the end result here is just `factor(e, p)`.